# How to make table header tooltip work with enabled sorting?

Tags: reactjs, antd

Here is the code ([live codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/0326964w8v)):

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Table, Tooltip } from "antd";

const columns = [
  {
    title: <Tooltip title="Address">A</Tooltip>,
    dataIndex: "address",
    sorter: (a, b) => a.address.length - b.address.length,
    render: cell => <Tooltip title={cell}>{cell[0]}</Tooltip>
  }
];

const data = [
  {
    key: "1",
    address: "New York No. 1 Lake Park"
  },
  {
    key: "2",
    address: "London No. 1 Lake Park"
  },
  {
    key: "3",
    address: "Sidney No. 1 Lake Park"
  },
  {
    key: "4",
    address: "London No. 2 Lake Park"
  }
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} />,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```

When I hover table header, it shows plain tooltip instead of showing antd `Tooltip`:

[image]

However after disabling `sorter` the tooltip displays correctly:

[image]

How to make `Tooltip` and `sorter` work together?

Answer (score 5):

Looks like `sorter` [applies](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/table/Table.tsx#L875) `ant-table-column-sorters` css class, which causes [css](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/table/style/index.less#L157) to overlap the `Tooltip`.

A hacky way to fix this could be: apply title as a function, and override css:

```
const columns = [
  {
    title: () => <Tooltip title="Address">A</Tooltip>, // note it's func

    // apply custom css class, so we can track it
    className: "sorter-no-tooltip",

    dataIndex: "address",
    sorter: (a, b) => a.address.length - b.address.length,
    render: cell => <Tooltip title={cell}>{cell[0]}</Tooltip>
  }
];
```

and in `index.css`:

```
.sorter-no-tooltip .ant-table-column-sorters:before {
    content: none !important;
}
```

Actually it looks like an framework issue, so it [could be submitted](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/new/choose).

Answer (score 5):

Antd now supports a property for hiding sorter tooltip.

`showSorterTooltip`

This option is supported for Table as a whole or at column level.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is fixed, you can update version to 3.12.2. And apply title as a function:
title: () => (your ReactNode),

Comment: welcome at stack. Please consider formatting your answer code by enclosing it into \`\` marks: \` code goes here \` will result in `code goes here`

Comment: I would find a complete example code snippet here to put the tooltip in the th useful.